# Oracle SQL - Returning row of first occurrence by value

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have data in the following format:

```
ID     YRMTH       EVENT
1      201201        0
1      201202        0
1      201203        1
1      201204        0
1      201205        0
2      201304        0
2      201305        0
2      201306        0
3      201301        0
3      201302        0
3      201303        0
3      201304        1
3      201305        0
```

I want to return one row per ID with YRMTH and EVENT.  If an EVENT occurred (= 1), then I want the YRMTH when the event occurred and EVENT = 1.  If an EVENT did not occur (= 0), then I want to return the last month listed in YRMTH and EVENT = 0.

In this example, I want the following output:

```
ID     YRMTH       EVENT
1      201203        1
2      201306        0
3      201304        1
```

Essentially, the intent of this query is to identify the first month when an event occurred if one occurred at all.  If no event occurred, then I just want the last month where we have data.

I am thinking that I would need to use a window function (`PARTITION BY`), but I am open to any possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with aggregations.  Analytic functions are not needed:

```
select id,
       (case when max(event) = 1 then min(case when event = 1 then yrmth end)
             else max(yrmth)
        end) as yrmth,
       max(event) as event          
from table t
group by id;
```

Comment: I thought this.. but if `=1` will `MIN()` give the right one?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar . . . It does now that I've fixed the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with cte as
(select id,
 case event
 when 1 then yrmth
 else max(yrmth) over (partition by id order by yrmth) 
 end as yrmth,
 event,
 row_number() over 
 (partition by id
  order by case event when 1 then 1 else 0 end desc, yrmth desc) as rn
from your_table)

select id, yrmth, event 
from cte
where rn = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fc72/11)